# Laravel5 Eloquent: How to get a few articles from special condition?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, relationship, eloquent

First, I'm sorry my poor english.
I want to got highest views with 5 articles. 
I tried it, but I'm having problem with Eloquent query.

**laravel source**

```
<?php
    $up = "SELECT id FROM articles WHERE id IN (SELECT id from (SELECT id FROM articles ORDER BY view_count DESC LIMIT 0,5) x)";
    $builder = new \App\Article;
    $query = $builder->selectRaw("articles.*, $up");
?>
    @forelse($query->latest() as $article)
        <img src="{{ $article->thumbnail }}" alt="{{ $article->title }}" title="{{ $article->title }}">
    @empty
        <p class="text-center text-danger">
        empty...
        </p>
    @endforelse
```

**DB query result**

```
MariaDB [test]> SELECT id FROM articles WHERE id IN (SELECT id from (SELECT id FROM articles ORDER BY view_count DESC LIMIT 0,5) x);
+------+
| id   |
+------+
| 4018 |
| 4045 |
| 3800 |
| 4011 |
| 4005 |
+------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I've seen the other posts on this topic, but i didn't get the solution.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: maybe you should check out this 

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#retrieving-single-models

pretty helpful

Comment: also your code is not clean, seriously look into laravel docs.

Comment: Why two sub-queries? Dosn't the inner query give same result as the query you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to your services sttuf in the controller to clean up the views and to respect the MVC pattern.

So in the controller you can use Eloquent to do that :

```
$articles = App\Article::orderBy('view_count', 'desc')
               ->take(5)
               ->get();

return view('SomeView')->withArticles($articles);
```

And in `SomeView.blade.php` :

```
@forelse($articles as $article)
    <img src="{{ $article->thumbnail }}" alt="{{ $article->title }}" title="{{ $article->title }}">
@empty
    <p class="text-center text-danger">
    empty...
    </p>
@endforelse
```

Answer (score 0):

5 articles ordered by views you just need to write in your controller:

```
$articles = Article::orderBy('views', DESC)->take(5)->get();
return view('article', ['articles' => $articles
]);
```

in your article.blade.php:

```
@forelse($articles() as $article)
    <img src="{{ $article->thumbnail }}" alt="{{ $article->title }}" title="{{ $article->title }}">
@forelse
    <p class="text-center text-danger">
    empty...
    </p>
@endforelese
```